# Limpiar RecyclerView para realizar nueva búsqueda

Tags: android, android-studio, jsoup

**Buenas, estoy intentado limpiar el `RecyclerView` para realizar una nueva búsqueda. Es decir, por ejemplo. Busco "suerte" en un `EditText` presiono el `Button` y se me llena el `RecyclerView`. Ahora bien, necesito ingresar una búsqueda con la palabra "casa" y presiono el `Button`. Pero, el `RecyclerView` sigue con los datos de "suerte" y no me muestra nada de "casa".

**Adaptador:**

```
public class ParseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ParseAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<TrantorItems> trantorItems;
    private Context context;

    public ParseAdapter(ArrayList<TrantorItems> trantorItems, Context context) {
        this.trantorItems = trantorItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ParseAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.vista_recycler, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ParseAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        TrantorItems trantorItems = this.trantorItems.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(trantorItems.getTitle());
        holder.idioma.setText(trantorItems.getIdioma());
        Picasso.get().load(trantorItems.getImgUrl()).into(holder.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return trantorItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView, idioma;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
            super(view);
            imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            idioma = view.findViewById(R.id.tvIdioma);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int itemPosition = getAdapterPosition();
            context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(trantorItems.get(itemPosition).getUrlDescarga())));
        }
    }

    public void setFilter(ArrayList<TrantorItems> newList) {
        trantorItems = new ArrayList<>();
        trantorItems.addAll(newList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void updateData(ArrayList<TrantorItems> items) {
        this.trantorItems = items;
    }
}
```

Donde se cargan los datos de la búsqueda:

```
private class Content extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, ArrayList<TrantorItems>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<TrantorItems> items) {
            super.onPostExecute(items);
            //Actualizar información
            adapter.updateData(items);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<TrantorItems> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            String url = "https://trantor.is/search/?q=" + textoBusqueda.getText().toString();
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

                Elements data = doc.select("div.row");
                int size = data.size();
                Log.d("doc", "doc: "+doc);
                Log.d("data", "data: "+data);
                Log.d("size", ""+size);
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    String title = data.select("div.span1")
                            .select("img")
                            .eq(i)
                            .attr("alt");
                    String imgUrl = data.select("div.span1")
                            .select("img")
                            .eq(i)
                            .attr("src");

                    String detailUrl = data.select("div.span1")
                            .select("a")
                            .eq(i)
                            .attr("href");

                    String urlDescarga = data.select("div.span3")
                            .select("a")
                            .eq(i)
                            .attr("href");
                    String idioma = data.select("div.span7")
                            .select("span.muted")
                            .eq(i)
                            .attr("");

                    if(!isNullorEmpty(title) && !isNullorEmpty(imgUrl)){
                        imgUrl = "https://trantor.is" + imgUrl; //Add basepath
                        detailUrl =  "https://trantor.is" + detailUrl; //Add basepath
                        urlDescarga =  "https://trantor.is" + urlDescarga; //Add basepath
                        trantorItems.add(new TrantorItems(imgUrl, title, detailUrl, urlDescarga, "Idioma: Pendiente"));
                        Log.d("items", "title: " + title + " img: " + imgUrl  + " urlDescarga: " + urlDescarga);
                    }
                }
            }  catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return trantorItems;
        }
    }
```

El **botón**:

```
buscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                hideKeyboardFrom(getApplicationContext(), textoBusqueda);
                if(new Conexion().isOnline(TrantorActivity.this)){
                    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(textoBusqueda.getText())){
                        Toast.makeText(TrantorActivity.this, "Debe ingresar el nombre del libro.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        textoBusqueda.setFocusable(true);
                    }else{
                        Content content = new Content();
                        content.execute();
                    }
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(TrantorActivity.this, "Se requiere conexión a internet.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

¿Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Comment: En tu método updateData del Adapter, debes limpiar los datos (`trantorItems.clear();`) luego agregar los datos (`trantorItems.addAll(items)`) y luego notificar los cambios al adaptador, `notifyDataSetChanged();`. Puedes utilizar `DiffUtil` para mejor performance. El problema es que simplemente estas cambiando la referencia de la lista, pero nunca debes hacer esto para tu `Adapter` porque altera su comportamiento, además de que no estás notificando los resultados al mismo. Saludos.

Comment: Elimina los elementos de la lista , revisa mi respuesta @FranqoBalsamo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limpia la lista en el metodo `doInBackground()` :

```
@Override
        protected ArrayList<TrantorItems> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    //Limpia lista     
    trantorItems.clear();
    ...
    ...
```

De esta forma cuando se agreguen los elementos se realizará en una nueva lista.